# Serialize route function for multiple dynamic sections Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

So ember has some good documentation on how to use a serialize function when you have a dynamic segment other than the `id`. However, I couldn't find proper documentation to serialize a route with multiple dynamic segments.

Example:

```
this.resource('people', function() {
    this.resource('person', { path: ':person_id/:first_name-:last_name' });
    this.route('add');
});
```

How would I go about serializing this route?

```
serialize: function(person) {
    return { what? };
},
```

So in the documentation it says: *If the route has multiple dynamic segments or does not contain 'id', serialize will return Ember.getProperties(model, params)*

Does this mean that I need to

```
serialize: function(person) {
    return Ember.getProperties(person, params); ?
},
```

I'm a little confused, so if someone could clarify what it meant in the documentation and accompany it by an example, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to return an object that has each dynamic slugs (:id) as a key with the associated value.

```
serialize: function(person) {
    return { 
      person_id: person.get('id'),
      first_name: person.get('first_name'),
      last_name: person.get('last_name')  
    };
},
```

The router doesn't support `-` as a separator between dynamic slugs.  It will just consider it as two different params `person_id` and `first_name-:last_name`.  You'd need to use `/` as your separator.